# If $lx+my=1$ is the equation of the chord $PQ$ of $y^2=4ax$ whose focus is $S$. If PS andQS meet the parabola again at R and T, find the slope of RT

Tags: conic-sections

Let $P(t_1)$ and $Q(t_2)$

The slope of PQ is 
$$\frac{2}{t_1+t_2}=-\frac lm$$

Also $R(\frac{-1}{t_1})$ and $T(\frac{-1}{t_2})$

Slope of $RT$
$$\frac{-2}{\frac{1}{t_1}+\frac{1}{t_2}}$$

But I can’t eliminate the $t_1t_2$ term by simply substituting the values. The answer is  $-\frac 1m$

Comment: The slope of PQ is $\frac{4a}{t_1+t_2}=-\frac lm$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(\frac{t_1^2}{4a}, t_1)$ and $Q(\frac{t_2^2}{4a}, t_2)$. Substitute $lx+my=1$ into $y^2=4ax$,

$$y^2+\frac{4am}ly-\frac{4a}l=0$$

which leads to,

$$t_1+t_2 = -\frac{4am}l,\>\>\>\>\>t_1t_2 = -\frac {4a}l\tag 1$$

With the focus at $(a,0)$, the points $R(\frac{t_R^2}{4a}, t_R)$ and $T(\frac{t_T^2}{4a}, t_T)$ respectively satisfy

$$\frac{t_R-0}{\frac{t_R^2}{4a}-a} = \frac{t_1-0}{\frac{t_1^2}{4a}-a}, \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\frac{t_T-0}{\frac{t_T^2}{4a}-a} = \frac{t_2-0}{\frac{t_2^2}{4a}-a}$$
which yields

$$t_R = -\frac{4a^2}{t_1},\>\>\>\>\>t_T = -\frac{4a^2}{t_2}$$
Then, the slope of the chord $RT$ is

$$ {Slope}_{RT}=\frac{t_T-t_R}{\frac{t_T^2}{4a} - \frac{t_R^2}{4a}} =- \frac{t_1t_2}{a(t_1+t_1)}=-\frac1{ma}$$

where the results (1) are used in the last step.